# Unity Launcher accordion effect does not work

Tags: unity, launcher

How to activate Unity Launcher accordion effect?
Actually luncher has scrolling effect.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer to the question:
Log Out, In the "Log In" options select Ubuntu and not Ubuntu 2D (Ubuntu 2D does not support Accordion Effect).

Back to the problem, I realised when I log in as Ubuntu it is switching to Ubuntu 2D i think there is problem with my graphic card driver. I did try GNOME 3 environment, the same problem I cannot log in GNOME only GNOME Classic.

It is new Asus Eee 1225C Ubuntu 12.04 LTS preinstalled netbook.
Actually it is Ubuntu Desktop certified (tested) hardware but it does not work.
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201203-10695/

Please help.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a screenshot of your Unity Launcher?

Comment: He cannot include a screenshot since he doesn't have enough reputation.

Comment: Please upload your screenshot to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) then post the link here.